# InfluxDB and Prometheus as backend for metrics with labels. Which one?

Tags: telemetry

this is yet another one of those "which one is better" questions, and the opinionated responses are very much welcome here. 
To start, currently I am running InfluxDB as a backend for metrics data, which I push to it periodically. It works quite well in almost all cases. 
**Almost** is the keyword here.

Already couple of time I had to augment the way a particular measurement looks. What I mean to say is that I collect basic stats of several systems' loads and push them to the DB. Here is an example:

```
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
node-load
> select * from "node-load"
name: node-load
time                location  cluster    cpu                mem
----                --------  -------    ---                ---
1558557610623032900 localtest Cluster1   3.104509464491694  24.716893236776354
1558557610623032900 bldg2     Cluster2   12.235501464212623 5.992881002266444
1558557615648050400 localtest Cluster1   3.062846891815933  24.769080916965557
1558557615648050400 bldg2     Cluster2   12.234410122386111 7.002993844412234
...
```

now if I decide to add another label/value to this measurement it doesn't work, as the schema is different. Here is what I mean:

```
time                location  cluster    cpu                mem                operator
----                --------  -------    ---                ---                --------

1558557610623032900 localtest Cluster1   3.104509464491694  24.716893236776354 devops
1558557610623032900 bldg2     Cluster2   12.235501464212623 5.992881002266444  finance
1558557615648050400 localtest Cluster1   3.062846891815933  24.769080916965557 devops
1558557615648050400 bldg2     Cluster2   12.234410122386111 7.002993844412234  finance
...
```

As I understand InfluxDB doesn't support database migration to add another label, but I think Prometheus does, as the list of labels that I can add to a particular measurement is flexible.

To wrap it up and actually ask a question. I am more than happy to continue using InfluxDB rather, if not for the above problem. So, did anybody hit a similar issue and how did you resolve it? Does anybody know if InfluxDB has a migration tool for existing measurements to add a "null" label for the old data?